# Spark read 403 error, but dbutils doesn't have issue in Databricks with Azure Blob

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

All within the same notebook cell on a cleared state fresh cluster restart.

After setting my spark confs:

```
spark.conf.set(..auth type)
spark.conf.set(...provider type)
spark.conf.set( token provider)
```

I am able to connec to a blob/adls location abfss://myname@myhost.com/mytable/ using dbutils

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://myname@myhost.com/mytable/")
```

which produces the expected output of a list of the folder's conents.

When I try to read the dataframe

```
spark.read.format("delta").load("abfss://myname@myhost.com/mytable/")
```

I am faced with a 403 : server failed to authenticate the request.  This was the case prior for dbutils, but fixing proxy settings resolved this issue.

I realize one uses directory listing and one is using Spark, but what would cause Spark to have a 403 (I assume a proxy issue) but dbutils not to?

I have tried checking proxy settings, curling & netcat the port 443 on the host from the notebook, and restarting clusters.

Comment: Does dbutils run on the driver? if so that could translate to the workers are having some network issue the driver isn't.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to allowed permission on your storage account using that token.
You can see below allowed permission to storage account.

[image]

You can see there is no permission for **Read**, **Write** and **Delete**.
So, if i try to read any file gives error.

[image]

So check this in storage account once and allow necessary permissions.

Even though you enabled all permission and, still you're getting error
then check the allowed resource types.

[image]

Make sure you enabled **Object**.
And get the new token, run the code after restarting the cluster.

After enabling the necessary permission i got output.

[image]

Comment: It ended up being tied to network issues.

Comment: 403 is server refusing your request.

Comment: I know, and i had trsted in storage explorer so no perm issue and i mentioned it worked with dbutils. The issue was resolved when network related work someone had done was rolled back.